# How can I create a custom connection between two different keras layers in LeNet5 architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

I am working on [LeNet5](https://engmrk.com/lenet-5-a-classic-cnn-architecture/) architecture. I want to implement a custom connection between the layers C3 and S2 as explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhya.png). How do I have to define my model in "**CODE-1**" and "**CODE-2**" if I want to implement the custom connections as explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhya.png). How many filters should I take in "**CODE-2**". Any type of help will be appreciated.

The output of s2 is 14*14*6 and 16 filters need to be applied on these 6 feature maps. However, instead of all 6 S2 maps to 16 neurons of c3, most neurons in layer C3 maps are connected to neurons in only three or four S2 maps. More details can be found in Images 2 and 3.
c3 layer with 16 feature maps having size 5×5 and a stride of 1. In this layer, only 10 out of 16 feature maps are connected to 6 feature maps of the s2.

If you notice image 3, neuron 0 of c3 is connected to 0, 1, and 2 feature maps of s2. How to implement this kind of connections.

My code is something similar below:

```
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Concatenate, Lambda
```

**CODE-1**

```
inputTensor = Input(shape=(14, 14, 6))
group0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:3], output_shape=((10, 10, 1)))(inputTensor)
group1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,1:4], output_shape=((10, 10, 1)))(inputTensor)
group2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,2:5], output_shape=((10, 10, 1)))(inputTensor)
group3 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,3:6], output_shape=((10, 10, 1)))(inputTensor)
# all 16 layers of c3 (of the Custom Connections image)
```

**CODE-2**

```
conv_group0 = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0)
conv_group1 = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group1)
conv_group2 = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group2)
#all 16 layers convolution

output_layer = Concatenate()([conv_group0,conv_group1,conv_group2,conv_group3,conv_group4,conv_group5,conv_group6,conv_group7,
                         conv_group8,conv_group9,conv_group10,conv_group11,conv_group12,conv_group13,conv_group14,conv_group15])
Mymodel = Model(inputTensor,output_layer)
```

Comment: I don't see what custom connections you are talking about in your images, can you clarify?

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro The output of s2 is 14*14*6 and 16 filters need to be applied on these 6 feature maps. However, instead of all 6 S2 maps to 16 neurons of c3, most neurons in layer C3 maps are connected to neurons in only three or four S2 maps. For example, if you notice image 3, neuron 0 of c3 is connected to 0, 1, and 2 feature maps of s2. How to implement this kind of connections. More details can be found in Images 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create the following custom layer classclass:**

```
CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
""" Custom layer with initialize matrix = connect_matrix. """
def __init__(self,  activation, units, connect_matrix):
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
    self.units = units
    self.connect_matrix = np.asarray(connect_matrix, dtype='float32')
    self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=self.connect_matrix), trainable=True)
    self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)
    self.m = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=self.connect_matrix), trainable=False)
    #super().build(batch_input_shape)
def call(self, inputs):
    wm = tf.math.multiply(self.w, self.m)
    out_lin = tf.matmul(inputs, wm) + self.b
    return self.activation(out_lin)
def get_config(self):
    base_config = super().get_config()
    return {**base_config, "units": self.units, "activation": keras.activations.serialize(self.activation)}
```

Save you connection matrix as a 2D numpy array, A, and use
CustomLayer(units, activation, connect_matrix=A)
as a usual tf.keras.layer
You can find more at the following link:
[CustomTF2KerasObjects](https://github.com/yboryshchak/CustomTfKerasObjects/blob/main/CustomTFKerasObjects.py)